# Start solution build from VSIX command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I'm creating a Visual Studio Extension and want to create a command to build the current solution and start debugging afterwards, so that I have to press one button and wait instead of starting build, waiting and then run.

How can I call Visual Studio's default commands from my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [ExecuteCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.executecommand) like `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Start");`